# Ubuntu Server flooding network with MPCP Opcode Pause packets

Tags: networking

I have been tearing my hair out (what little I have left) with this issue for a few weeks now but I have finally made a little progress towards finding what the problem is.

The symptoms are that after a certain amount of time (say 30 minutes to 10 hours) all 3 of my machines that are connected to the same switch stop responding to pings or ssh.

I have finally found that this is because one of the machines (and the machine that causes it can change) suddenly starts flooding the network with the following packets:

`20:10:26.441796 MPCP, Opcode Pause, length 46
20:10:26.442321 MPCP, Opcode Pause, length 46
20:10:26.442845 MPCP, Opcode Pause, length 46`

This stops absolutely all network activity and as these 3 machines are headless it was really tricky to find this out.

All 3 machines are identical Ubuntu Server 16.4 builds without much installed on them. Motherboard (which I suspect is the root of the problem) is ASRock H110 Pro BTC+

They are all mining rigs so basically have tmux, nano, nvidia drivers, mining software (Claymore), node, git, ssh and that's about it.

I have re-installed all 3 machines and the problem recurs on a fresh install.

I have updated and upgraded all packages.

Now that I have found what is breaking the network I REALLY hope someone can help me out with a solution!

On my knees begging!!

Thanks

Comment: Hair restorers? (sorry, couldn't resist) /// Have you seen this: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=709616 It's old, but seems to apply.

Comment: Looks like it might be a bug in the igb network driver:  https://sourceforge.net/p/e1000/bugs/477/

Comment: @PerlDuck - yes I did see that but found it hard to follow the thread. There didn't seem to be any resolution and was from 5 years ago so possibly not relevant any more?

Comment: i had the very same problem. Do you use cylclenerds ethereum mining ubuntu? @Roaders

in my case the probleme solution seemed to be a very absurd one: it was to cold for the lan adapters to work properly. avoid temperatues bellow 5 degree and very dry air.

Comment: @Roaders -  any update?

Comment: This seems to be an issue with my motherboard: asrock H110 BTC Pro+. I am using Claymore miner on Ubuntu Server

Comment: Sucks that there's no solution for this, I have this exact same issue with a chinese USB -> gigabit adapter. My wireshark log is just full of these pause packets.